# Instantly open files when navigating the file explorer with arrow keys in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently, I navigate the file tree in **VScode** with arrow keys and have to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to display the file in the editor.

Is there any way to navigate through the file explorer in **VScode** AND instantly open the file upon focus/highlight without shortcut ? (similarly to how it works in sublime text)

Comment: I would totally appreciate this in cases where I'm browsing a large new code base.

Comment: Haven't figured this out, but there is an "Open File..." command with an unassigned keybinding. When I try adding it (workbench.action.files.openFile
) to a command is keybindings.json, it says that that command does not exist... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_file-management

Comment: Maybe think the behavior you're looking for is to `preview`, instead of `open` each file?

Answer (score 13):

As written in this github issue: [(Open File Preview when using Keyboard navigation in Explorer for better accessibility. #55816)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55816), as of (at least) the 28th of august 2019 it is possible to

#### **preview** files, by selecting them in the explorer with **<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>** and pressing **<kbd>space</kbd>**

One can easily switch to the file-explorer with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
This is not as simple as just the arrow-keys, but still way more convenient than what is described in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Goal: Glance review a lot files in project via `Explorer` view of VS Code.

Here is a bit long (but easy to follow) procedure - Once done, you will save a lot of time later.

---

1 . Install `multi-command` extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command

2 . Menu > File > Preferences > Settings
or, `Ctrl + ,`

3 . Click on "Open settings (JSON)"  button on top-right

4 . Paste below:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.navigateExplorerDownAndPreviewFile",
      "sequence": ["list.focusDown", "filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus"]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.navigateExplorerUpAndPreviewFile",
      "sequence": ["list.focusUp", "filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus"]
    }
  ],
```

5 . Menu > File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts
or, `Ctrl K + Ctrl S`

6 . Click on `Open Keyboard Shortcuts JSON` button on top-right

7 . Paste below two entries, into your array

```
[
    {
        "key": "down",
        "command": "multiCommand.navigateExplorerDownAndPreviewFile",
        "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !explorerResourceReadonly && listFocus && !inputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "up",
        "command": "multiCommand.navigateExplorerUpAndPreviewFile",
        "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !explorerResourceReadonly && listFocus && !inputFocus"
    }
]
```

8 . Menu > View > Explorer
or, `Ctrl Shift E`

9 . Select any file on left side in explorer

You can open a folder that has multiple files (for example, .js files)

10 . Try below keyboard shortcuts to open next/previous file

- Press `up arrow` to go to previous file, and view it in the middle pane
- Press `down arrow` to go to next file, and view it in the middle pane

---

Now, you are setup to preview files using only `up` & `down` arrow keys, via explorer in vs code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot 