# VSCode: Preview file in tab/panel

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When previewing a file by clicking on it once in VSCode, is it possible to preview other files in the explorer by using the arrow keys, similar to Visual Studio? When I do it, it just selects the file, but doesn't preview it (unless I use my mouse). I'd provide a picture, but the upload isn't working right now, sadly. :(

I feel like that used to be a thing and I broke it at some point, but I could also just imagine it due to VS.

Comment: Up/Down Arrow to the file and then use `Space`, to open its preview see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774167/836330

Comment: Do you want to make it so that a simple downArrow opens the next preview without having to hit `space`?  That can be done.  Let me know, it is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch! I followed the steps from the same question with the 'multi-command' extension and this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237216/12903844 has exactly what I was looking for!

Short summary: Up/Down + Space will enable you to preview a file, but you can also use 'multi-command' to macro it to just Up/Down (without having to press Space when selecting files this way).

---

Credit goes to Mark for answering it in the comments, just adding it here so the solution is marked. <3